# How to show json at same level for interface nested inside struct?

Tags: json, go

Here has an interface `SpecificTemplate` nested inside struct `Template`:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
)

type SpecificTemplate interface {
    GetLabel() string
}

type TemplateA struct {
    Label string `json:"label"`
}

func (t TemplateA) GetLabel() string {
    return t.Label
}

type Template struct {
    Id int64 `json:"id"`
    SpecificTemplate
}

func main() {
    ta := TemplateA{
        Label: `label1`,
    }
    t := Template{
       Id:               1,
       SpecificTemplate: ta,
    }

    data, _ := json.Marshal(t)
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

It would be

```
{
    "id":1,
    "SpecificTemplate":{
        "label":"label1"
    }
}
```

I wanna kown how to show json at same level, just like:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "label":"label1"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flattening marshalled JSON structs with anonymous members in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362147/flattening-marshalled-json-structs-with-anonymous-members-in-go)

Answer (score 0):

It kinda depends on the level of complexity you wanna reach...

If you want to expose only the label I should advice you to create a MarshalJSON function, just like this...

```golang
func (t Template) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        Id int64 `json:"id"`
        Label string `json:"label"`
    }{
        Id: t.Id,
        Label: t.SpecificTemplate.GetLabel(),
    })
}
```

With this your `json.Marshal(t)` will call this function and you will receive a flattened json...

However if you want to expose more Fields from the template you should use reflection, as pointed out by Iain Duncan in his comment