# How do I embed an interface inside of a struct without the interface name becoming a key inside of the JSON?

Tags: go

I have an interface, EventAggregation, that is implemented by many different types. I need to enrich all of these types with the same two fields so I'm doing something like this:

```
type messagePayload struct {
    domain.EventAggregation
    SourceSystem     string `json:"sourceSystem"`
    MessageTimestamp int    `json:"messageTimestamp"`
}
```

I then translate that to a string with this method:

```
func (payload messagePayload) payloadToString() string {
    jsonForm, _ := json.Marshal(payload)
    return string(jsonForm)
}
```

But it creates a string with "EventAggregation" as a key and the fields are embedded as an object within it like this:

```
{"EventAggregation":{"startTime":1575941942501,"endTime":1581461995869,"computeTimestamp":1582573485983,"eventType":"foo","count":146692},"sourceSystem":"bar","messageTimestamp":1582573497406}
```

How do I create the string in a way such that the fields within the EventAggregation are at the same level as the fields "SourceSystem" and "MessageTimestamp"? Like this:

```
{"startTime":1575941942501,"endTime":1581461995869,"computeTimestamp":1582573485983,"eventType":"foo","count":146692,"sourceSystem":"bar","messageTimestamp":1582573497406}
```

The same code seems to work if the embedded object is a struct instead of an interface but that isn't super practical given how many different structs implement the "EventAggregation" interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flattening marshalled JSON structs with anonymous members in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362147/flattening-marshalled-json-structs-with-anonymous-members-in-go).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you question, maybe it can help you:

```
type messagePayload struct {
    domain.EventAggregation `json:"-"`
    SourceSystem     string `json:"sourceSystem"`
    MessageTimestamp int    `json:"messageTimestamp"`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The result of this though is: {"sourceSystem":"bar","messageTimestamp":1582659091509}. It ignores the whole object within "EventAggregation".

Answer (score -2):

All you need to do is ignore this file while json encoding.
Try this:

```
type messagePayload struct {
    domain.EventAggregation `json:"-"`
    SourceSystem     string `json:"sourceSystem"`
    MessageTimestamp int    `json:"messageTimestamp"`
}
```

To check out more tags supported visit:
https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

Comment: The tag body needs to be in quotes: `json:"-"`

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that.